# Python 2.7 string

Tags: python, string

I need to print **[something]** only one time, even if exactly the same string occurs next time. I tried this:

```
msg = "[something]" + random.randint(1,5)*str(random.randint(1,1000000000)) + "[something]"
i = msg[msg.index('['):msg.rindex(']')+1]
print i
```

but it works wrong. Message is prints up to last "]", I would like it to be up to the first "]". Between two "[something]" is randomly amount of strings. Is it posible with this code?

Comment: This might help: i = msg[msg.index('['):msg.index(']')+1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways you could do it:

```
import re

msg = "[something]" + random.randint(1,5)*str(random.randint(1,1000000000)) + "[something]"

print msg[msg.index('['):msg.index(']')+1]
print re.search("(\[.*?\])", msg).group(1)
```

Which will display:

```
[something]
[something]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `msg.index(']')` instead of `msg.rindex(']')` as the last method searches "]" from the end of the string. For more details, see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rindex).